# Select last 5 mysql rows

Tags: php, mysql

i want to get the last 6 rows but skip the last one in result:

```
SELECT * FROM stats_follow ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 6
```

How can i make this?

Comment: Use `... LIMIT 1, 6`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *
      FROM TableName
      ORDER BY FieldName DESC
      LIMIT 5) sub
ORDER BY FieldName ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM stats_follow ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1,6
```